# Select and read first record of table and delete record after that, in one stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I want to read records one-by-one and delete them after read. Table is a temp table, a multi thread program will use data of table. I need to read each record just once and not by multiple thread.
is there any solution by stored procedures to create this thread safe program(delete record just after read by first thread)?

Comment: Does your temp table have a column that can be used to uniquely identify the rows?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes it does, has an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I feel like I have to warn you that it's probably not the best idea to do it in SQL Server - relational databases works best with a set based approach, not on a row-by-row basis.
Reading and deleting each row individually will have a very poor performance.

Having said that, here's one way to delete a row, get it back to the client using the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#queues) clause, and (thanks to the [`rowlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) hint) do it in a thread safe manner:

```sql
DELETE TOP(1) 
FROM #tempTable WITH (ROWLOCK)  
OUTPUT deleted.*  
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your Stored Procedure code:

```
Create Procedure DeleteButOne
As
Begin
    Select TOP 1 * From "Your Table Name"
    DELETE FROM "Your Table Name" WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM "Your Table 
    Name")
End
```

And then you can execute procedure :

```
Execute DeleteButOne
```